# Tracking tableau data source usage with snowflake query_tag

Tags: tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are looking for usage stats on tableau data sources.  We are running tableau with snowflakes.  We have the raw queries, but cannot link the raw queries back to the data store name.

Tableau UI offers some usage stats, but we would like these stats at the data source level, not the workbook level.

Is there a way (either in tableau or snowflake) to track usage at this level, specifically linking the tableau data source to it's source query?

Comment: What is your definition of data source and workbook?  Do these map to Snowflake databases or schemas?

Comment: @MikeWalton, the tableau data-sources and workbooks can map to 1 to many snowflake tables. The data sources can also be custom queries containing multiple tables. All of these tables reside in the same schema and database on snowflake.

Comment: I don't know Tableau well enough to help you with how to do this, but as your title suggests, it sounds like a query_tag would be the easiest way to manage this.  If Tableau has the ability to specify the query_tag based on the data-sources and workbooks that the queries are being generated from, then you can report on that from Snowflake's side.